# Why isn't something hiding?

Tags: html, css

I've hidden a banner on [my blog](http://speakingwithpictures.com) using the below code:

```css
#collection-506d943d84aead5098d63cc2 #banner-area {
    display: none;
}
```

However, when I click on a post title, [it reappears](http://speakingwithpictures.com/2012/10/6/this-is-a-test-post-what-do-you-think).

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`collection-506d943d84aead5098d63cc2` is a class, not an id, so you don't specify it with a '#' in the CSS.

Comment: Squarespace generates and ID for each new page.